# Popup window always on top

Tags: javascript, html

Am looking at whatever hacks that are possible to keep a window always on top (apart from window.focus()). Maybe a hidden textbox to which I can set focus etc.

I see this happening in LivePerson (support) whenever a new message arrives. I have legitimate use of this and not to annoy users with ads or anything.

Any hacks for any browsers will do. I am not looking at a complete cross-browser solution. I think window.focus would work for Internet Explorer, though I am yet to test it.

Comment: Please don't do this, however legitimate your purpose if it's not optional it's unwelcome (albeit this is my own opinion, and causes me to leave sites even more rapidly than blinking banner ads).

Comment: See newer answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565310/create-a-window-that-always-remains-on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This JavaScript code will place the popup window on top of all other open browser windows until the viewer closes the window containing this little JavaScript code:

```
<body onblur="self.focus();">
```

Comment: My usual response to such code: Kill it! Kill it with Task Manager! (You are right, this will work for IE. That's one of the reasons I stay away from it whenever possible.)