# Create a window that always remains on

Tags: javascript, user-interface, window, user-experience

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Popup window always on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602802/popup-window-always-on-top)

In my web application, there is a button that opens a score chart. The chart is opened as a new window, so that the user can put it adjacent to the main window:

```
javascript:window.open('chart',..., 'left=50,top=50,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,directories=no,dependent=yes,menubar=no, width=400,height=600,scrollbars=yes')
```

However, when the user makes his main window full-screen, and then opens the score chart, and then clicks the main window - the score chart "disappears" under the main window.

How can I make the score chart stay always at the top (until the user closes it, of course)?

Other ideas to achieve the same goal will also be welcome...

Comment: You can't, JavaScript doesn't provide that kind of "always on top" functionality. The "best" you could do is continually focus the popup when they try to switch to another window, but that would be incredibly obnoxious, probably not achieve what you're hoping for, and is a really, really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery dialog to open the window as a "window" inside your main window that way the main window and the score chart are the same..

```
var $div = $("<div/>");
$("#OpenScoreChartButton").click(function() {
    $div.load('chart.aspx?... ', function() {
       $div.dialog(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

What about making a div positioned on top of the page instead of a browser window? Popup windows are usually prevented as default by browsers. One way to achieve this would be using a javascript plugin like this one: https://github.com/ajayhada/SimpleDialog/wiki, or maybe Jquery UI Dialog, see http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: see example to use jQuery UI dialog in my answer...